# Spring data jpa for between search: difference Between or IsBetween?

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

There is an ambiguity in Spring data jpa for searching something between ( date in my case), My IDE suggest both:

```
findByIdAndDateBetween
```

and

```
findByIdAndDateIsBetween
```

what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the [Spring Data JPA Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.predicate) Table 9, both expressions - `IsBetween` and `Between` - means `BETWEEN`, so: the are the same and there is no difference.

**Additional/Historical note**

First of all, only `Between` was allowed: [commit, that introduced `IsBetween` (and others)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/commit/a2e5cc439e1da2dc58f346ff3fbca4048ba084fb)

Comment: isn't it strange? Both do the same, and noone is deprecated?

Comment: I don't think it's strange: For a parser (that parses the method names and "is used to generate queries") I don't think it's a huge problem to treat two different keywords the same. And also, this is why I think it's good to allow both keyworkds: You can choose what (subjectively) sounds better or what fits your other (method name) conventions better.